# How to combine noisy and noise-free datasets to train a model

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, references, dataset

**Overview**

Suppose I have two datasets, both of which consist of rows of features and their matching labels. One of these datasets is noise-free and its labels correspond to the ground truth, but the other is corrupted and some proportion of its labels are randomly flipped.

**The question**

*How do we combine these datasets and account for their differing levels of noise?* Presumably we shouldn't just throw out the noisy data, but it seems like we should also treat it differently from the higher quality noise-free data.

Should we modify the loss function? How should we construct the training/validation/test sets? Should we train two models separately and then combine their predictions?

**My attempt at formalizing the problem**

Let $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{D}_\text{noisy}$ be the noise-free and noisy datasets, respectively. For simplicity, assume we are attempting to learn a deterministic binary function $f(x) \in \{0, 1\}$. Then a single example from $\mathcal{D}$ or $\mathcal{D}_\text{noisy}$ is a feature/label pair $(x,y)$. For all $(x,y) \in \mathcal{D}$, we have $y = f(x)$. But if $(x,y)$ comes from $\mathcal{D}_\text{noisy}$, then
$$
y = \begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{with probability }p \\
1 - f(x) & \text{with probability }1 - p, \\
\end{cases}
$$
where $p$ is known.

How do we combine $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{D}_\text{noisy}$, and how do we factor in the noise parameter $(1-p)$?

Comment: It sounds like you want a noisy data detector.  You need to have inputs to a function.   Something about the nature of the noisy vs not-noisy must be able to be extracted from that using functions you can use.  Then you can start making progress moving forward.